# Rewriting generated assembly into GCC inline assembly

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, clang, x86-64

In C I have:

```
struct segv_ctrl {
    _Bool volatile*volatile rfaulted_eh_ptr;
    _Bool volatile*volatile wfaulted_eh_ptr;
};
_Thread_local struct segv_ctrl segv_ctrl;
_Bool rfaulted_eh(char volatile*Ptr)
{
    _Bool volatile faulted=0;
    char c; _Bool r;
    segv_ctrl.rfaulted_eh_ptr = &faulted;
    #if 1
    c=*Ptr;
    r = faulted;
    #else
    //I'd like this to produce the same code as the #if block above
    //but I obviously have no idea what I'm doing :D
    __asm__ __volatile__ (
        "mov (%2),%0;\n"
        "mov %3,%1;\n"
        : "=r"(c), "=r"(r)
        : "r" (Ptr), "r"(faulted)

    );
    #endif
    return r;
}
_Bool wfaulted_eh(char volatile*Ptr)
{
    _Bool volatile faulted=0;
    _Bool r;
    segv_ctrl.wfaulted_eh_ptr = &faulted;
    #if 1
    *Ptr=0;
    r = faulted;
    #else
    #endif
    return r;
}
```

With clang -O1 to -O3 on x86-64 it very reliably generates:

```
c.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <rfaulted_eh>:
   0:   c6 44 24 ff 00          movb   $0x0,-0x1(%rsp)
   5:   48 8d 44 24 ff          lea    -0x1(%rsp),%rax
   a:   64 48 89 04 25 00 00    mov    %rax,%fs:0x0
  11:   00 00 
  13:   8a 07                   mov    (%rdi),%al
  15:   8a 44 24 ff             mov    -0x1(%rsp),%al
  19:   c3                      retq   
  1a:   66 0f 1f 44 00 00       nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)

0000000000000020 <wfaulted_eh>:
  20:   c6 44 24 ff 00          movb   $0x0,-0x1(%rsp)
  25:   48 8d 44 24 ff          lea    -0x1(%rsp),%rax
  2a:   64 48 89 04 25 00 00    mov    %rax,%fs:0x0
  31:   00 00 
  33:   c6 07 00                movb   $0x0,(%rdi)
  36:   8a 44 24 ff             mov    -0x1(%rsp),%al
  3a:   c3                      retq
```

I'd like to take the

```
mov    (%rdi),%al
mov    -0x1(%rsp),%al
```

part and the

```
movb   $0x0,(%rdi)
mov    -0x1(%rsp),%al
```

part and turn them into reusable, inlinable assembly snippets.

My very unsuccessful attempt is shown in the elided #if block above.
Can you please explain why it's wrong and it's possible to make this work with inline assembly?

(I'm using this to detect segfaults cheaply (if there wouldn't be a segfault). If I know the length of the possibly segfaulting instruction, I can skip right past it in my SIGSEGV handler without having to have made a relatively expensive sigsetjmp, but gcc isn't generating such reliable code so I'd like to force it to.)

Comment: How can you jump past the faulting instruction without knowing the length? FWIW I tried to figure out what you were doing here. But it's difficult for me to given I'm used to Intel assembly (-masm=intel). Also, have you considered simply writing the entire function in assembly?

Comment: @Micrified You can't. That's why I'm trying to generate known instructions.

Comment: (Actually you can do it by disassembling the current instruction in the sigsegv handler - something I've done before :)).

Comment: @Micrified That's definitely an adequate and easy to implement solution, but I though I'd try and figure out how to do it with inline assembly. Reading up more on it now.

Comment: @Micrified Interesting approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second line is just loading the `faulted` from the stack, you don't need that in asm and it won't ever fault (assuming the previous initialization didn't fault). You can use

```
"mov (%1), %0" : "=a" (c) : "D" (Ptr)
```

and

```
"movb $0, (%1)" : "=m" (*Ptr): "D" (Ptr)
```

where `a` is the appropriately sized sub-register of `rax`, which is `al` for 8 bits. `D` is the `rdi` register. `=` means output. `m` is a generic memory operand used to tell the compiler the asm is writing into memory at `*Ptr`. Could be omitted here since your `Ptr` is `volatile` so the compiler will not cache the value, but it doesn't hurt.